# How to use Django models in for loop?

Tags: django-models

```
Query = 'com pu'
Query = Query.split()
busi = ""
for data in Query:
    busi += Business.objects.filter(Keywords__icontains=data)
```

When I use '+' symbol after busi variable for add all data according to filter that give error

> Exception Type:   TypeError
>
> Exception Value:Can't convert 'QuerySet' object to str implicitly

How can I achieve that different Query part which split by that all give different-2 data and and both data in single busi object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Q
Query = Query.split()
query = Q()
for data in Query:
    query |= Q(keyword_name__icontains=data)
Business= Business.objects.filter(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use &:

```
busi = None

q = Business.objects.filter(Keywords__icontains=data)

if busi is None:
    busi = q
else:
    busi = busi & q
```

Comment: Here what is data and what will you  get in q ?What you want try? if busi is None: ?

Comment: q is the small chunk that you will get for each i (the way you were trying). It is just adding the querrysets. initially busi is naone as you have put empty string. The error you are getting is because of that as you cannot add an string to a queryset (busi).